# Jax-rs -jersey Cross Origin request enablement

Tags: java, tomcat, jax-rs, cors, jersey-2.0

I am trying to make my very first jersey rest api, using version 2.X but i have a problem about CORS.

Before configuration files, this is my curl output:

```
 curl -i http://localhost:8080/camp/rest/user/register
 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
 Content-Type: application/json
 Content-Length: 32
 Date: Sat, 07 Feb 2015 15:34:28 GMT
```

From browser i can get right output, there is no problem about it. But i couldnt enabled cors with my tomcat server.

Here is my web.xml

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
         <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
        <display-name>camp</display-name>
         <servlet>
         <servlet-name>camp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
                 org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
        </servlet-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.yigit.camp.api.out</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.yigit.camp.api.security</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.glassfish.jersey.container.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
            <param-value>com.yigit.camp.api.security.CORSResponseFilter</param-value>
        </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>camp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>

  <init-param>
      <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
      <param-value>*</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
      <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
      <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
      <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
      <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And here is my Filter class:

```
package com.yigit.camp.api.security;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter;

@Provider
public class CORSResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext creq, ContainerResponseContext cres) {
    cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "");
    cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "");
    cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "");
    cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "");
    cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "");
}

}
```

I did same configuration on tomcats web.xml too, but result is the same.

What is the right way to solve this problem?

Regards guys

Comment: You should be using JSONP as your content type, not JSON.

Comment: I updated my code with JSONP object type as you told but result is the same, i need to enable cors. I just tried that now.

Comment: You're setting your content type wrong `Content-Type: application/json`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this in your web.xml:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
    <param-value>com.yigit.camp.api.MyAppConfig</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Then add this class:

```
package com.yigit.camp.api;
public class MyAppConfig extends Application {
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        final Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();        
        classes.add(CORSResponseFilter.class);        
        return classes;
    }
}
```

Now your response filter should be used.

Comment: It works ;) thank you, this code makes me register this filter to application right?

Comment: Yes, you can even do a RequestFilter if you need to, just implements `ContainerRequestFilter` in a similar way of `ContainerResponseFilter`.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is for tomcat server

Add following code to your web.xml and add following two jars to your build path
* coarse-filter-1.7.jar 
* java-property-utils-1.7.1.jar

add this web.xml

```
 <filter>
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
     <param-name>cors.allowOrigin</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
     <param-name>cors.supportedMethods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET, POST, HEAD, PUT, DELETE</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.supportedHeaders</param-name>
    <param-value>Accept, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Last-      Modified</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.exposedHeaders</param-name>
        <param-value>Set-Cookie</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.supportsCredentials</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

For more info refer

---

### https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html